# Get phone number in "+1 (303) 123-4567" format

Tags: c#, libphonenumber

I am using libphonenumber-csharp and when I make the following call:

```
PhoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.GetInstance();
var phoneNumber = PhoneNumberUtil.Parse(e164PhoneNumber, null);
return PhoneNumberUtil.Format(phoneNumber, PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL);
```

I get "+1 303-123-4567". How can I instead get "+1 (303) 123-4567"?

Is my best bet to use regular expressions and if it's "+1 ###-###-####" then adjust it? I think that would be safe as the +1 tells me it's U.S.

Comment: The unit tests suggest you can make a [custom format](https://github.com/twcclegg/libphonenumber-csharp/blob/7f80fb67da38eb9578ff88b52433940f8fe5a43e/csharp/PhoneNumbers.Test/TestPhoneNumberUtil.cs#L846). It does not seem like a great idea, but you can.

Comment: The above seems a bit fragile and probably wrong for non-US numbers. Do you need it for non-US numbers as well?

Comment: @teapot418 I'd like number for any country to be formatted in the standard for that locale? The standard for the U.S. is "(303) 123-4567" not "303-123-4567". So any way to get the local standard?

Comment: I'm afraid the available libraries follow [E.123](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-E.123-200102-I/en) and your desired format is a mix of the national and international format, which is unlikely to be directly supported.

Comment: Don't forget about extensions.  We all have a 3-digit extension at work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did. It works. And it uses the libphonenumber returned string if it's not exactly "+1 303-123-4567..." and so should be safe. Keep in mind this does not need to handle all possible phone formats. It only needs to handle the format libphonenumber returns.

```
   private static PhoneNumberUtil? PhoneNumberUtil { get; }

   static MiscUtils()
    {
        PhoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.GetInstance();
    }

   public static string FormatPhoneNumber(string e164PhoneNumber)
    {
        if (PhoneNumberUtil == null)
            return e164PhoneNumber;

        var phoneNumber = PhoneNumberUtil.Parse(e164PhoneNumber, null);
        var formattedNumber = PhoneNumberUtil.Format(phoneNumber, PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL);
        // returns "+1 650-253-0000", maybe with an extension
        if (!PhoneRegex.IsMatch(formattedNumber))
            return formattedNumber;
        // Want "+1 (650) 253-0000"
        return $"+1 ({formattedNumber[3..6]}) {formattedNumber[7..]}";
    }
```